# How to refresh Spring boot applications deployed on all Kubernetes pods on DB update

Tags: java, spring-boot, event-handling, hotswap

I am working on a Spring boot application, which is deployed on 3 Kubernetes pods.

In my application, there is an API component, through which new rules can be added to the DB or existing rules can be edited.

Now, this application has one more component, the Rule Engine, which basically starts up at the time application gets started, reading existing rules from DB.

Now, my goal is to automatically refresh the rule engine component of my application, as soon as any rule in the DB added/updated, basically I want a hot-swappable-like feature.

Here, I have thought of using SQS initially, but then I realized, with SQS, I can refresh application instances only on a single POD, but not all PODs. So I cannot use SQS here.

In this context, I have gone through a few articles here, but not getting any idea regarding how to do it.

Comment: How about integrating with Spring Cloud to trigger those registered applications to update rule(s)? Or you can also achieve this by using Pub/Sub mechanism with queue.

Comment: @LHCHIN, the queue does not seem to work, as with the queue I can update only one POD. But it would be difficult to refresh all PODs. Please correct me, if I am wrong.

Could you please elaborate a little bit on, how can I achieve with Spring cloud ?

Comment: If you're using queue and all the pods subscribe the same topic for updating rules, they can receive the message published by someone else in the same time. And if you are using Spring Cloud, registering all pods to the same registry, then you can trigger them to update rules via registry.